# Get posts with WP-REST without authentication

Tags: wordpress, rest, authentication, wp-api

I'm new to WP-REST API and Wordpress in general. I've tried to get the posts list using the endpoint wp-json/wp/v2/posts but I get the classic 403 error.

I'd like to ask if there is a way to disable authentication for GET requests like posts, categories and so on since I want to create a web application in which a user can navigate and see them freely, with no need for authentication.
Thank you all for the answers.

Comment: I think wp-json/wp/v2/posts use you can get list of post without Auth, you check your configuration and you can check with fresh WP installation.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to have authorization to merely `GET` posts or categories, so long as they aren't password protected.

If someone has implemented a modifier to `rest_authentication_errors`, that might be your problem: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/frequently-asked-questions/#require-authentication-for-all-requests

To see the available endpoints you have, visit `yourwordpressurl.com/wp-json`